# Missing "Add and Remove Software" in kde plasma

Tags: apt, kubuntu, kde, snap, debian

There no `add and remove software` in my newly installed `kde plasma`. I am extremely familiar with `apt` or `snap` but for now I really need that `Add and Remove Software` in my `KDE` Desktop Environment. Help me plz. I am in debian based Ubuntu.

Comment: You haven't provide release details, but KDE (and modern Lubuntu which also uses Qt) provide the *Muon package manager*  (Qt's equivalent of GTK's `synaptic`) and `discover` (Qt equivalent of Ubuntu/GNOME Software).  I would expect both those options exist in your *unstated* release (Discover will install both snaps & deb packages, muon only handles deb packages just like synaptic does).

Comment: I have `Ubuntu 20.04` installed. And desktop enironment `DE: KDE 5.68.0 / Plasma 5.18.5`